# How to add hover effect to hyperlink images?

Tags: html, css, hyperlink, hover

I created social media hyperlicks with images(social media icons) and want to add a hover effect to these images which is not working. I am trying to add hover effect to the images which are in hyperlink tag.

my code is:

```
<div class="icons">
  <a href="ex.fb link here">     <img class="fb"     src="images/fb.png"> </a>
  <a href="insta">               <img class="insta"  src="images/insta.png"> </a>
  <a href="//wa.me/number">      <img class="whatsapp" src="images/whatsapp.png"> </a>
  <a href="youtube.com/channel"> <img class="yt"     src="images/yt.png"> </a>
</div>
```

I want to set hover effect to these img's in hyerlink so when anyone hovers, img will reduce some opacity by (opacity : 0.5%;). How to accomplish this task?

Following code worked on the localhost webpage :

```
.icons a:hover img{
  opacity: .2;
  transition: all .75s;
  -webkit-transition: all .75s;
}
```

But this code is not working on the live webpage :(
(I have same index.html for both local and live webpage still this code is only working in localhost page only.)

Comment: try ```.icons a:hover img{opacity: .5}```

Comment: Thank you so much sir, I searched everywhere but not found this :)

Comment: This syntax worked fine on the localhost webpage, but not working on the live webpage.

Comment: what s the url to the webpage?

Comment: it works good on that url on the very bottom

Comment: icons are at the bottom of the webpage

Comment: On my Chrome browser its not working on the live webpage I refreshed also

Comment: do you ve anydesk?

Comment: What desk?? I think if icons hover opacity is working on your computer then my browser needs to clear cache memory. hope it will solve it.

Comment: Yes it will ?  do it. If not download this https://anydesk.com/en and let's chat

Comment: @Gildas.Tambo Sir thanks for your help, Clearing browser data worked for me, Thank You :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

user the `:hover` [CSS pseudo-class](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:hover)

```css
a {
  width: 150px;
  display: inline-block;
}

img {
  width: 100%;
}


/* Selects any <a> element when "hovered" */

.icons a:hover img {
  opacity: .5
}
```

```html
<div class="icons">
  <a href="ex.fb link here"> <img class="fb" src="https://i.imgur.com/9r1qCDq_d.jpg?maxwidth=800&shape=thumb&fidelity=high"> </a>
  <a href="insta"> <img class="insta" src="https://i.imgur.com/9r1qCDq_d.jpg?maxwidth=800&shape=thumb&fidelity=high"> </a>
  <a href="//wa.me/number"> <img class="whatsapp" src="https://i.imgur.com/9r1qCDq_d.jpg?maxwidth=800&shape=thumb&fidelity=high"> </a>
  <a href="youtube.com/channel"> <img class="yt" src="https://i.imgur.com/9r1qCDq_d.jpg?maxwidth=800&shape=thumb&fidelity=high"> </a>
</div>
```